# Reviewing after flagging

Tags: bug, flagging, review-system

Several times, I've seen an inappropriate post under "new questions", flagged it, found it in a queue, and been unable to review it (specifically, unable to flag it, and so unable to click the "I'm Done" button) to remove it from the queue. I can skip it, but often the flag is the correct response to it being in the queue. Is there a way to correct this?

Comment: This bug report (on Meta Stack Exchange) seems a bit similar: [Took an action on a post already but the First Posts review queue sometimes doesn't activate “I'm Done” button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/264349) (However, it got no response.)